# SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 does not resolve the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send. (C#)

Tags: c#, wcf

I deployed a WCF web service on IIS (https, TLS1.2) last year, 2019 and the client code implemented `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` , and it connected to the web service URL successfully and started working perfectly.

I ran into a problem this year saying

> the underlying connection was closed. An unexpected error occurred on a send.

I checked the web service URL SSL certificate if it is still on TLS1.2, and it is.

The client code to test the connection is shown below:

```
    public bool TestConnection(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            myRequest.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
            myRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 30000;
            myRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            myRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            myRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, chain, ssl) => true;

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //well, at least it returned...
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: TLS1.2 works. Hard-coding it is a workaround needed only for .NET versions below 4.6 though, and the OS has to support it anyway. *Supported* OS versions work with TLS1.2 out of the box. Older ones like SQL Server 2008R2 required patching. Did that client forget to patch their OS?

Comment: What are the .NET and OS versions of the client?

Comment: The client runs 4.7.1 .net framework and Windows 10

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it was working before. In fact it worked for a year like I reported in the question above without any issues running on Windows 7 and 10 until this month.

Comment: Nothing changes this month, except even more services turned off TLS1.1. In .NET 4.7.1 you *don't* need to use `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`, .NET uses the OS's best algorithm automatically. Windows 7 isn't supported and [requires configuration to support TLS 1.2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi), so if the customer deployed to Win7, they already had to patch. Perhaps they forgot it this time

Comment: Or there's a misconfiguration on IIS and it no longer uses TLS1.2? Browse to the service URL and click on the lockpad to see the certificate details. Or use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to intercept the calls to the service and check the TLS version used during the handshake.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, 
I have checked this too on the browser, and it is still valid on TLS1.2 and not yet expired. I discovered that Windows 7 clients connected to the web service without this error but only windows 10. However, the client machine runtime target is 4.5.2 `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />` while the .NET framework installed on the client machine is 4.7 for Win 10. I wouldn't know if I should switch the runtime target to 4.7.2 may be the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most possible cause is that the certificate is expired if the WCF service and the client-side work properly before.
Are you using a self-signed certificate for transport layer security? Also, please try not to specify a TLS version for communication.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Before we call the remote service again, I suggest you navigate to the service URL using a browser and check for certificate errors. The error message displayed by the browser should help you troubleshoot what's causing the error.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: I have checked this too on the browser, and it is still valid on TLS1.2 and not yet expired. I discovered that Windows 7 clients connected to the web service without this error but only windows 10. However, the client machine runtime target is 4.5.2 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" /> while the .NET framework installed on the client machine is 4.7 for Win 10. I wouldn't know if I should switch the runtime target to 4.7.2 may be the issue will be resolved.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be related to client configuration. But I'm sure where the problem lies. I suggest you refer to the following article. Then re-add the service reference on the client.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: But why is it still working with windows 7 on .net framework 4.5.2 without connection issue?